Вытащить имя файла, без разделения строки
os.path.basename(file).rsplit(".", 1)[0]

Как по мне, это жесть какая та. Чтобы получить имя фала, приходиться на такое идти...
Есть ли в пайтоне вариант, адекватного получения имени файла, без разделения...

os.path.splitext? Правда, это тоже по сути разделение

вопрос философский. a.b.c.d - что здесь является «именем файла»? a или a.b или a.b.c или a.b.c.d? и, главное - почему?

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что недостаточно информации для хорошего ответа на этот вопрос. Нужно дополнить примерами этих "имен файлов" и что в итоге хотелось бы получить.

import pathlib
f="d:\\documents\\proba.txt"
print(pathlib.Path(f).stem)

Выводит: "proba"
